# print reverse pattern of alphabets using functions in python

Tags: python

I have written following code:

```
def  contalpha(n):
    num = 65
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            ch = chr(num)
            print(ch, end=" ")
            num = num +1
        print("\r")
n = 7
contalpha(n)
```

The output is:

```
A 

B C 

D E F 

G H I J 

K L M N O 

P Q R S T U 

V W X Y Z [ \
```

but what I want is:

```
A B C D E
A B C D
A B C 
A B 
A
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise against using `chr`. Ascii can be confusing, instead just use a string of all capital ascii characters (which is a sequence of characters, and can be handily found in the `string` module).

```
import string

def contalpha(n):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        print(*string.ascii_uppercase[:i], sep=' ')

contalpha(5)
```

outputs:

```
A B C D E
A B C D
A B C
A B
A
```

Comment: I am not a Python programmer, so maybe I don't know something important here, but can you tell me what can be confusing in terms of ASCII and it's capital letters block?

Comment: I don't know about you, but to me `string.ascii_uppercase` is more obvious than `[chr(i) for i in range(65, 91)]`. Basically, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for reply, this really a simple way

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the range in order to start from the bigger row `range(0, n)[::-1]`. Then you need to set `num = 65` every time you start a new row for it to always start from `A`.

There you go:

```
def  contalpha(n):
    num = 65
    for i in range(0, n)[::-1]:
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            ch = chr(num)
            print(ch, end=" ")
            num = num +1
        num = 65
        print("\r")
n = 7
contalpha(n)
```

Output

```
A B C D E F G 
A B C D E F 
A B C D E 
A B C D 
A B C 
A B 
A
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def  contalpha(n):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        num = 65
        for j in range(0, i):
            ch = chr(num)
            print(ch, end=" ")
            num = num +1
        print("\r")
n = 7
contalpha(n)
```

First you need to set `num` to `65` every outer loop to get alphabets from `A` again and second you should reverse outer loop range to print from max size to min size.

output:

```
A B C D E F G 
A B C D E F 
A B C D E 
A B C D 
A B C 
A B 
A
```